# Is it possible run a plugin as a test?

Tags: javascript, html, unit-testing, testing

I'm working with HTMLhint but it just run with the command line is a plugin, I want this action to run like a test. Is it possible do it and how? I was googling but I don't find a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you'd like it to run every time you push code? Or, would you like it to run locally in your editor every time you save/as you type?

Every time you push code: look into [TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/) or another type of continuous integration. These services can run items on your code, including linters, each time you push new commits.

Every time you save/as you type: this depends on what your editor requires to run the lint. For example, Sublime Text has [Sublime Linter](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter) which can automatically run any type of linter after [installation of the corresponding package](https://packagecontrol.io/).

Comment: Yes, I want to run it every time I push code, in fact I'm working with CircleCI, but I'm trying to learn how to implement other tests I did to it. Right now my concern is convert HTMLhint to a test or do something similar. That explanation that CircleCI runs linterns is very helpful, i'm going to review some info about it.